# jQuery $("#elementID").click interfers with other elementIDs

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, webforms

Htmlshot: http://fallenhero.mysteria.cz/Leetleaflet.htm

Scenario: When I check "Polozka 1", then select "Pulena" and uncheck "Polozka 1", everything works well. But when, after doing the above mentioned process, I check "Polozka 2", the "Polozka 1 box" suddenly appears. Revelation of the "Polozka 1 Box" is bounded to checking "Polozka 1", not "Polozka 2".

Can anyone explain this odd behavior?

Code of the event handlers:

```
  $('#frmletakForm-polozka1').on("click", function(){
     var pulena1Box = $("#pulena1Box");
     var radioPulena1 = $("#frmletakForm-typpolozky1-1");
     if(!$(this).is(":checked") && radioPulena1.is(":checked")) {
      pulena1Box.toggle();
     }
   });
  $('#frmletakForm-polozka2').on("click", function(){
     var pulena2Box = $("#pulena2Box");
     var radioPulena2 = $("#frmletakForm-typpolozky2-1");
     if(!$(this).is(":checked") && radioPulena2.is(":checked")) {
      pulena2Box.toggle();
     }
   });
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I don't see this happen in my browser.

Comment: It happens both in my Firefox 7.1 and Chrome 17.0.939. What browser do you use?

Comment: i see errors in javascript when the page is loaded "bar.dom() is undefined"

Comment: These JavaScript errors occur only at the htmlshot. But it doesn't work without those errors either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is caused with your use of `nette.toggle`

For example the code

```
    visible = true; val = nette.getValue(form["typpolozky1"]); res = (val=="p"); visible = visible && res;

    nette.toggle("pulena1Box", visible);
```

Is only checking the value of the select list and not if the enclosing container is visible.

Since this whole function is run for all of the aux items -- they will get shown each time there is a change in the form if the item they are checking is selected.

Comment: Thank you! It was too hard form me to somehow combine JavaScript and the Nette API so I just added the condition you said to the form creation script. 

          $form->addHidden("kontrolaBoxu"+$i)
            ->addConditionOn($form['typpolozky'.$i], NForm::EQUAL, 'p')
             ->addConditionOn($form['polozka'.$i], NForm::EQUAL, 'TRUE')
              ->toggle('pulena'.$i.'Box');

Answer (score 1):

You better do something like, then you don't have to repeat all the 1,2,3,4 number for each checkbox, and have less code.

```
$('[id^="frmletakForm-polozka"]').on("click", function(){
    var num = this.id.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");
    var pulenaBox = $("#pulena" + num + "Box");
    var radioPulena = $("#frmletakForm-typpolozky" + num + "-1");
    if(!$(this).is(":checked") && radioPulena.is(":checked")) {
        pulenaBox.toggle();
    }
});
```

I also get these errors from your page:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined Leetleaflet.htm:1446
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined saved_resource.htm:735
5Unable to post message to http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net. Recipient has origin http://fallenhero.mysteria.cz.
```

Comment: Thank you, it looks much more elegant now. But it still isn't working. These errors are only in the htmlshot and have no influence on box toggling.